# Audio Streaming in C

Tags: sdl, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I am working on this project in which we've got to implement real time audio streaming. Think of it as more or less a phone conversation, so the audio data that is fed in needs to be played while being fed.

I want to know if there are any libraries (Linux) that would enable me to do this. If this can be done via [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) it would be great because we are already using SDL for many other purposes.

Answer (score 3):

This is doable using SDL. [SDL_OpenAudio](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_OpenAudio) provides lowish level access to the audio device, registering a callback function that is called from a separate thread that will fill the audio buffer with sound data whenever it is ready for more.